# ol.layer.Tile.TileLayer is not a constructor

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping

This is the code that OpenLayers provides for a quick startup point:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';

new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({source: new OSM()})
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  }),
  target: 'map'
});
```

However, since I'm importing using a CDN, instead of importing specific modules I specify the full path instead, for example `ol.source.OSM()` instead of `OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'`. This works for each component except TileLayer, which returns the error "ol.layer.Tile.TileLayer is not a constructor". I know I can just use `ol.layer.Tile` but TileLayer seems to have better panning bounds. I've checked for version problems and I'm using the latest version of ol, what could be the problem?

Comment: You always have to look at the last part of import. In your case, if you look at the `import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'`, the last part tells you that it should be `ol.layer.Tile`.

Comment: @TomazicM Now that you say it, I realise I didn't do ol.source.OSM.OSM(), thank you! So what's the deal with `TileLayer` then?

Comment: I have no experience with imports, but I would say it could also be  `import MyTileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'`. It's just an arbitrary name, probably used to differentiate between `ol.source.Tile` and `ol.layer.Tile`.

Comment: @TomazicM I see, that does make sense, thank you so much for answering!! :)